# [ros2/rclcpp] Threadsafety of Node::create_publisher<>

Tags: ros, ros2, rclcpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can't find any documentation of whether or not creating and working with nodes is threadsafe in rclcpp. My specific use case is that I would like to

create node A <- In thread 1

rclcpp::spin(A) <- in thread 2

Add/remove publishers/subscribers <- In thread 1

A link to the documentation on this topic or a direct answer would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280108/%5Bros2/rclcpp%5D-threadsafety-of-node::create_publisher%3C%3E/) by [ipiano](https://answers.ros.org/users/33331/ipiano/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2018-01-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Creating and destroying (allowing them to go out of scope) publishers and timers is thread-safe right now. For Subscriptions, Service Servers, and Service Clients, creation is currently thread-safe, and destroying them was intended to be, but there are some on going issues about that here:

https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/issues/349

and

https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/pull/431

Long term hopefully all of the actions will be thread-safe (that's the goal). Also we hope to improve the documentation soon too, but anyone could help with that I think.

On a related note, adding and removing nodes to/from executors is also thread-safe. So you could do something like this:

```
#include <thread>

#include <rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp>
#include <std_msgs/msg/string.hpp>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  rclcpp::init(argc, argv);

  rclcpp::executors::SingleThreadedExecutor executor;

  auto node = std::make_shared<rclcpp::Node>("test");
  executor.add_node(node);

  std::thread t([&executor]() {
    executor.spin();
  });

  {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    auto pub = node->create_publisher<std_msgs::msg::String>("chatter");
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    pub.reset();
  }

  {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    auto sub = node->create_subscription<std_msgs::msg::String>(
      "chatter",
      [](const std_msgs::msg::String::SharedPtr msg) {(void)msg;});
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    sub.reset();
  }

  {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    executor.remove_node(node);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    executor.add_node(node);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    node.reset();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
  }


  executor.cancel();
  t.join();
}
```

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2018-01-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0